# How to match a portion of string and reject on whole string?

Tags: c#, regex

I have an array with these four elements: 
`[0]: //some data` 
`[1]: /some data` 
`[2]: for i = 1 to 10` 
`[3]: foreach i`

I want four regex’s to check 
1) if string starts with `/` and not `//` 
2) if string starts with `//` 
3) if string starts with `for` and not `foreach` 
4) if string starts with `foreach`

For `//` I used `^//.*` and it's working good, but I don't know how to match `/` and reject `//`.

For `foreach` I used `^foreach`, but I can't figure out how to match `for` only.

**EDIT:** 
`for` and `foreach` are just sample data.
It may be only `for` followed by nothing.
And I want to use the match length

Comment: Are you trying to parse a language with regex? Maybe a parser would be a better fit.

Comment: No, it's an example!

Comment: For 2 and 4, you can just use the `.StartsWith()` method of the `string` class.

Comment: Yes, I know, but in my case I have an array of regex's and a loop to check which pattern is matching, that's why I need to reject.

Comment: I was reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference and I thought `^((for)|(?!foreach))` would work, but it didn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ought to do you:

```
class PatternMatch
{
  public string Prefix { get; private set; }
  public string Suffix { get; private set; }

  private static Regex rxValid = new Regex(@"
    ^                           # start of line, followed by
    (?<pfx>                     # one of...
    ( /  ( [^/] | (?= $ ) ) ) # a slash (but not slash slash!)
    | ( //                    ) # two slashes
    | ( for(?! each )         ) # for (but not foreach)
    | ( foreach               ) # foreach
    )                           # , followed by...
    (?<sfx> .* )                # zero or more extraneous characters, followed by
    $                           # end-of-line  
  ", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

  public static PatternMatch TryMatch( string s)
  {
    Match m = rxValid.Match(s);
    PatternMatch instance = m.Success ? new PatternMatch(m) : null ;
    return instance;
  }
  private PatternMatch(Match m)
  {
    if (!m.Groups["pfx"].Success | !m.Groups["sfx"].Success) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("m", "The match needs to be successfull");
    this.Prefix = m.Groups["pfx"].Value;
    this.Suffix = m.Groups["sfx"].Value;
  }
}
```

Here's a test case:

```
static void Test()
{
  string[] text =
  {
    "//some data",
    "/some data",
    "for i = 1 to 10",
    "foreach i",
  };

  foreach (string s in text)
  {
    PatternMatch pm = PatternMatch.TryMatch(s);
    if (pm == null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("NO MATCH: {0}", s);
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("MATCHED:  {0}", s);
      Console.WriteLine("  Prefix: len={0}, value={1}", pm.Prefix.Length, pm.Prefix );
      Console.WriteLine("  Suffix: len={0}, value={1}", pm.Suffix.Length, pm.Suffix ); 
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! `(for(?!each))` is what I wanted.

Comment: `^/[^/]` on `/test` or `/[SPACE]` gives me `/t` or `/[SPACE]`, I used `^/(?!/)` instead, is it ok or there's another way?

Answer (score 0):

String starts with `/` and not `//`: `^/[^/].*`

String starts with `//`: `^//.*`

String starts with `for` and not `foreach`: `^for\s.*`

String starts with `foreach`: `^foreach\s.*`

Comment: And what if I want a portion of text like `te` instead of `test`?

Comment: well then you've got to be a lot more specific with what sort of data you have in your strings

Comment: I don't know any regex, is \s mean whitespace?

Comment: `\s` is whitespace. It can be \t \n \r or just a space. Alternatively you can use `^for\b.*` to match for and not foreach

Comment: It may be only `for`, I used `for` and `foreach` for example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say

Comment: I tested the `^for\s.*` on `for` itself but it doesn't match, and it matches the whole string on `for i = 0` but I only wanted the for and match.Length to be 3

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, just use `^for(?=\s.*)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need regex when the `string` class already has a `StartsWith` method, which you can use as-is for your #2 and #4 requirements. For #1 and #3, you can combine it with `!input.StartsWith` to get your result.

Here's an extension method you could use:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool StartsWithThisButNotThat(this string input, string startsWith, 
        string notStartsWith = null)
    {
        if (input == null) return startsWith == null;
        if (startsWith == null) return false;
        if (notStartsWith == null) return input.StartsWith(startsWith);
        return input.StartsWith(startsWith) && !input.StartsWith(notStartsWith);
    }
}
```

And in your main code, then, you could test it like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var codeLines = new List<string>
    {
        "//some data",
        "/some data",
        "for i = 1 to 10",
        "foreach i",
    };

    foreach (var codeLine in codeLines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(codeLine);

        Console.Write(" - starts with / and not //".PadRight(40, '.'));
        Console.WriteLine(codeLine.StartsWithThisButNotThat("/", "//"));

        Console.Write(" - starts with //".PadRight(40, '.'));
        Console.WriteLine(codeLine.StartsWithThisButNotThat("//"));

        Console.Write(" - starts with for and not foreach ".PadRight(40, '.'));
        Console.WriteLine(codeLine.StartsWithThisButNotThat("for", "foreach"));

        Console.Write(" - starts with foreach".PadRight(40, '.'));
        Console.WriteLine(codeLine.StartsWithThisButNotThat("foreach"));

        Console.WriteLine("\n" + new string('-', Console.WindowWidth));
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I have a list of patterns to check, I had issues finding the correct pattern for these four, actually I didn't know how to use `(?!xxx)`